# Trouble converting Excel to R Dates

Tags: r, excel, date

I have uploaded a CSV from Excel which has a column of dates.

The first 5 of these dates is the following:

```
dates <- c("25/09/2016","25/09/2016","25/09/2016","25/09/2016","25/09/2016", "25/09/2016")
```

When I use the following code:

```
as.Date(dates)
```

The result is

```
"0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20"
```

I've tried setting the origin to Excel's origin date:

```
as.Date(dates, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

But the result is still the same

```
"0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20" "0025-09-20"
```

Any ideas why it's not converting properly and what I should do?

Comment: Simply add `"%d/%m/%Y"` (your date format): `as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: or from the `lubridate` package: `lubridate::dmy(dates)`

Answer (score 0):

With excel, you need to be very careful on the format under which the date is stored.

If your dates are in a character format, you need to use `as.Date(dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`. This will work for a character date in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

For others format of excel date, you need to modulate the format following the specifications gave in [that link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

If your dates are in a numeric format, you need to use `as.Date(dates, origin = "1899-12-30")` for windows excel and `as.Date(dates, origin = "1904-01-01")` for mac excel.